# Configuring MEX and service in separate sections in web.config

Tags: wcf

I have basic question - can we assume that both configurations does the same thing?

web.config one

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="endpointBehavior" name="mYwebSrv.mYDevice">
            <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="mYwebSrv.ImYDevice"></endpoint>
</service>

<service behaviorConfiguration="endpointBehavior" name="mYwebSrv.mYDevice">
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
</service>
```

web.config two

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="endpointBehavior" name="mYwebSrv.mYDevice">
            <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="mYwebSrv.ImYDevice"></endpoint>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
</service>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly.
Since you declared a new Service in your Web.config, it cannot have the same key for both services (endpointBehavior and name).

As you want to expose an endpoint to your service and an endpoint for the same service but for metadata (mex), it makes sense to put both under same service, that is as Microsoft recommends, see here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734765.aspx

```
<service
      name="Metadata.Example.SimpleService"
      behaviorConfiguration="SimpleServiceBehavior">

    <endpoint address=""
              binding="wsHttpBinding"
              contract="Metadata.Example.ISimpleService" />

    <endpoint address="mex"
              binding="mexHttpBinding"
              contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
```

Hope it helps.